# Call CGPatternCreate in Swift

Tags: ios, core-graphics, swift

I'm wondering how to convert the following objective-c method to Swift function?

```
CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL,
                                       rect,
                                       CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                                       24,
                                       24,
                                       kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                                       true,
                                       &callbacks);
```

My code:

```
    let callbacks : CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(version: 0)

    let pattern : CGPatternRef = CGPatternCreate(nil,
        rect,
        CGAffineTransformIdentity,
        24,
        24,
        kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
        true,
        callbacks)
```

But I got an error message:

> 'CGPatternCallbacks' is not convertible to 'CConstPointer'

Is there any sample code for this? Thanks

Comment: callbacks can not be defined as const

Comment: You're right. It works when I use var and &callback. But here comes a new problem in my next statement: CGContextSetFillPattern(context,pattern,1.0). I got an Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'CConstPointer<CGFloat>'. I know it's because the third parameter. But I don't know what to do?

Comment: You will have a lot of problems with that, what do you use Swift for Core Graphics? Use obj-c and wrap all that stuff

Comment: I'm trying to learn Swift in my new project. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Common problem, if you want to learn swift - learn swift, but not apply swift where is no need to do that.

Comment: You're right. Maybe Swift is not ready for everything yet.

Comment: I ran into similar problems; I created a gist with the approach I took given that Swift 2.0 has better support for C function callbacks https://gist.github.com/BenziAhamed/bcbed0054a6b572c9d8d. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that

```
var callbacks : CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(version: 0)

var pattern = CGPatternCreate(nil,
    rect,
    CGAffineTransformIdentity,
    24,
    24,
    kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
    true,
    &callbacks)
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It only work when I wrote it this way: var callbacks : CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(version: 0)

Comment: @bagusflyer, how do you mean does not work? that looks syntactically a quote correct solution.

Comment: @bagusflyer Why did you accept this if it doesn't work? And where's your CGDrawPatternCallback function?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a problematic one:

The pointer registered within CGPatternCallbacks (for a function that draws the pattern) should be CFunctionPointer<(UnsafeMutablePointer, CGContext>)->Void) 
This means that the function pointer should be transformed to UnasfeMutablePointer then to COpaquePointer then to CFuncfionPointer

And still anyway i'm getting an exception on function call, there is a simplier solution: 
[http://www.raywenderlich.com/90695/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-3][1]

Answer (score 2):

1. Option 1

   ```
   //global function - outside of the class  
   func myDrawColoredPattern(info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, context: CGContextRef?) -> Void {
       //draw pattern using context....
   }   

   var callbacks : CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(version: 0, drawPattern: myDrawColoredPattern, releaseInfo: nil)

   let pattern: CGPatternRef? = CGPatternCreate(nil, rect, CGAffineTransformIdentity, 24, 24, CGPatternTiling.ConstantSpacing, true, &callbacks)
   ```
2. Option 2 - the 'swift' way

   ```
   let drawPattern: CGPatternDrawPatternCallback = { (_, context) in
           //draw pattern using context...
   }

   var callbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(version: 0, drawPattern: drawPattern, releaseInfo: nil)

   let pattern: CGPatternRef? = CGPatternCreate(nil, rect, CGAffineTransformIdentity, 24, 24, CGPatternTiling.ConstantSpacing, true, &callbacks)
   ```