# CGPatternCallbacks in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert the sample information given in Quartz 2D Programming guide (page 101 & 102 ) into swift, however encountered with an error in the call back implememenation, any help to solve this would be much appreciated. Here is my full code

```
   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //Step 1

  //  refer to function MyDrawStencilStar


   //Step 2

    let baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(baseSpace)
    CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, patternSpace)

    //Step 3

    var callback : CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks (version: 0, drawPattern: &MyDrawStencilStar,releaseInfo: nil)
```

//.......I am getting error in the line above aginst the pointer to drawPattern and the error is '(Void, context: CGContextRef) -> ()' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T3'

```
    var pattern =  CGPatternCreate(nil,
        CGRectMake(0, 0, Psize/2, Psize/2),
        CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
        Psize/2,
        Psize/2,
        kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
        false,
        &callback)



}




func MyDrawStencilStar (info : Void, context : CGContextRef) {


    var theta : Double = 0.0
    var r : Double = 0.0

    r = 0.8 * Double (Psize) / 2
    theta = 2 * M_PI * 2 / 5  //144 degrees

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, Psize/2, Psize/2)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, CGFloat(r))

    for var k : CGFloat = 0;  k<5; ++k {

        var  x : CGFloat = CGFloat(r) * sin(k * CGFloat(theta))
        var  y : CGFloat = CGFloat(r) * cos(k * CGFloat(theta))


        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x,  y)


    }

    CGContextClosePath(context)
    CGContextFillPath(context)

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Swift CFunctionPointer to pass a callback to CoreMIDI API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514176/using-swift-cfunctionpointer-to-pass-a-callback-to-coremidi-api)

Comment: The CoreGraphics API you're working with uses C function pointers, which Swift doesn't support. See the duplicate for more info.

Comment: check my answer at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179988/call-cgpatterncreate-in-swift/34024193#34024193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179988/call-cgpatterncreate-in-swift/34024193#34024193)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a problematic one:

1. The function 'MyDrawStencilStar' should get UnsafeMutablePointer
2. The pointer registered within CGPatternCallbacks should be CFunctionPointer<(UnsafeMutablePointer, CGContext>)->Void) 
   This means that the function pointer should be transformed to UnasfeMutablePointer then to COpaquePointer then to CFuncfionPointer

And still anyway i'm getting an exception on function call, there is a simplier solution: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/90695/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-3